# WPF NavigationService.Navigate not showing up in Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create a WPF application but I cannot navigate to a custom xaml file on a button click event. I am importing the navigation service method but for some reason the "NavigationService.Navigate" is not showing up. It only shows me NavigationService.GetNavigationService. Can anyone give me an idea what the issue might be?

[image: Image Here]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NavigationService.Navigate is part of Page object. If you inherit your XAML from

```
public partial class MainWindow : Page
```

instead of

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

If you want to navigate to a page from main window create a frame in mainwindow as below

```
<DockPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="_NavigationFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</DockPanel>
```

and then in your mainwindow constructor call

_NavigationFrame.Navigate(new CustomXml());

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the confusion CustomXaml is just the name of CustomPage.

I will use the following design for page navigation application

Steps 1: Create MainWindow.Xaml and add the following Code

```
 <DockPanel>
            <Frame x:Name="_NavigationFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
 </DockPanel>
```

Frame is a placeholder for all the pages.

Step 2: Create a main page MainPage.xaml (like home page) and place all the code you intend to place in MainWindow.XAML into this MainPage.XAML. To open this main page on application load add the following code in MainWindow.Xaml constructor

`_NavigationFrame.Navigate(new MainPage());` 
   where MainPage() is the constructor of MainPage.XAML

Step 3: Create a custom Page CustomPage.XAML (the page you want to navigate to).  In order to navigate to this page from first page

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("CustomPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: can you elaborate the (new CustomXml());" what format should my uri be?

Comment: Please see my edit to the above answer. Let me know if you are looking for the same or not?

Comment: How can I get to customPage.xaml from a click function on secondPage? And how can I get to a new page from a click function on the customPage.xaml?

Comment: place this code in the click method this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("CustomPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); . Replace the "CustomPage.xaml" page to the page name you want to navigate to. Let me know if you have issues with this