# How to navigate to other page with button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I have a second .xaml page set up under the name **`Page2.xaml`** and I want to make it so that when my button is clicked, the user is taken to **`Page2.xaml`**

I have this for my button inside of my **`Page1.xaml`**:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="localModeBtn" 
            Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}"  
            Content="local mode" 
            Click="localModeBtn_Click" />
</Grid>
```

And for the button event handler:

```
private void localModeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
    }
```

Upon clicking the button I receive an error that says "Cannot locate resource **`page2.xaml`**"
The thing is that **`Page2.xaml`** is in the same folder as **`Pag1.xaml`** so I can't see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Define "taken to".   You want it to load in Page1 or do you want to create a new Navigation Window?

Comment: Check my old post regarding page navigation design for WPF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071180/wpf-navigationservice-navigate-not-showing-up-in-expression-blend/17071514#17071514

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solution to my own question:

I feel a bit silly providing a solution to my own question but thanks to Jasti's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071180/wpf-navigationservice-navigate-not-showing-up-in-expression-blend/17071514#17071514) I was able to sort my code out. As he had only posted a comment, I can't mark it as an answer, so here is the solution.

I changed the NavigationWindow to a Window and inserted:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="_NavigationFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</DockPanel>
```

And within the constructor of the MainWindow.xaml.cs I added:

```
_NavigationFrame.Navigate(new Page1());
```

Then the last step was to adjust the button event handler to:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use this, this worked for [me](https://miladzandi.ir):

```
var Page2= new Page2(); //create your new form.
Page2.Show(); //show the new form.
this.Close(); //only if you want to close the current form.
```

There is a `variable type` of a page with the page.xaml right name in your solution.
after that, you should use its methods to do it functionally.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: D`accord! I it requires a short description.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any C# code for this, just do it in XML:

```
<Button Content="local mode"
    Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage"
    CommandParameter="/Page2.xaml"/>
```

(Reformatted code not tested)

Comment: My buttons becoming disabled when I'm trying to apply `Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage"`

Answer (score 0):

Use any container and bind the content to any property in your viewmodel or codebehind.
After that you just have to update the property by setting a new page and call the PropertyChanged-event (see INotifyPropertyChanged interface). This will update the content of your container and you can display anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a separate window

```
NavigationWindow navWIN = new NavigationWindow();
navWIN.Content = new pageWFbchAdmin();
navWIN.Show(); 
//winBchAdmin.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Navigate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//By Prince Jain 
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page3.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was adding a frame in the main window `MainWindow.xaml`

```cs
<Frame Name="Main" Content="" Margin="127,0,0,0" Background="#FFFFEDED" />
```

For navigation:

1- Navigating from the main windows on button click:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // navigate to pages/projects.xaml inside the main frame
   Main.Content = new MyProject.Pages.Projects();
}
```

2- In case of navigation from the page inside a frame ex `Projects.xaml`

```cs
// declare a extension method in a static class (its your choice if you want to reuse)
// name the class PageExtensions (you can choose any name)

namespace MyProject
{
    public static class PageExtensions
    {
        public static void NavigateTo(this Page page, string path)
        {
            Frame pageFrame = null;
            DependencyObject currParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(page);

            while (currParent != null && pageFrame == null)
            {
                pageFrame = currParent as Frame;
                currParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currParent);
            }

            if (pageFrame != null)
            {
                pageFrame.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
            }
        }
    }
}


// to navigate from 'pages/projects.xaml' to another page
// heres how to call the extension on button click

this.NavigateTo("NewProject.xaml");
```

In addition, you can add another extension method that expects another `Page` object, in case you want to pass parameters to the constructor

```cs
// overloading NavigateTo
public static void NavigateTo(this Page page, Page anotherPage)
{
    Frame pageFrame = null;
    DependencyObject currParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(page);

    while (currParent != null && pageFrame == null)
    {
        pageFrame = currParent as Frame;
        currParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currParent);
    }

    // Change the page of the frame.
    if (pageFrame != null)
    {
        pageFrame.Navigate(anotherPage);
    }
}

// usage
this.NavigateTo(new Pages.EditProject(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need a frame in your window to hold the pages, so in my MainWindow.xaml I'll add a frame like this:

```
<Frame x:name="mainFrame"/>
```

Then We'll add an event listener to our navigation button in our MainWindow.xaml like this:

```
<Button
    x:Name="navBtn"       
    Content="LIVE VIEW"       
    Click="NavBtn_Click">
</Button>
```

Now after we've set our window xaml up, we'll go to MainWindow.xaml.cs and write our code:

```
//this function should be automatically generated
private void NavBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        //we'll write this line, which opens our page
        mainFrame.Content = new YourPage(); 
    }
```

and that's it your navigation is ready!

Answer (score 0):

In View (.xaml file):

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Outside area of frame</TextBlock>
    <StackPanel Height="20" Width="400" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Page 1" Width="200" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Page 2" Width="200" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame Name="Main" Height="300" Width="700" Background="LightGray">
    </Frame>
</StackPanel>
```

In code behind (.xaml.cs file):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new Page1();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new Page2();
    }
```

Thesse two buttons will now help you to navigate between pages named Page1 and Page2. (Please take care of namespaces if the pages are present in folders or so).