# How to navigate from a pop-up dialog window to another page in wpf i'm not using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to navigate to another page when a user selects an option from a WPF dialog window. From page1, I pop up the window with this code via a button click event

```
private void newCust_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bvnQuery bv = new bvnQuery();
        bool? val = bv.ShowDialog();

        if (val.HasValue && val.Value)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate("page3.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }
    }
```

then on the dialog window, I selected a Yes/No option(button), when I returned the value to the calling function, I get a blank page when I navigate to the page in the URI above. How do I work around this?

Comment: Are you using NavigationService?

Comment: yes, i am using this                 NavigationService.Navigate("page3.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
but it is not navigating to the page

Comment: Try adding the Navigation Service into your button click method?

Comment: @AGrammerPro i have done that

Comment: not sure if you have checked this out or not so I'll post it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787622/how-to-navigate-to-other-page-with-button-in-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `DialogResult` property of your `bvnQuery` window in your "Yes/No" handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

This value will be returned from the `ShowDialog()` method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bvnQuery bv = new bvnQuery();
    bool? val = bv.ShowDialog();

    if (val.HasValue && val.Value)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not navigating to the required page when i do this                 NavigationService.Navigate("page3.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
within the if block. val returns true

Comment: i have updated my question with updates from the code sample you provided. Thanks

Comment: My bad. I'm sorry for the confusion. you are right  i was supposed to do this NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("page3.xaml", UriKind.Relative));. Thanks